# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

```
   File albumF = getVideoAlbumDir();
   String path = albumF.getAbsolutePath();

// path =/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/.MyImages (Hidden folder)
// fileSelected.fileName()=IMG_20140417_113847.jpg

   File localFile = new File(path + "/" + fileSelected.fileName());

        Log.v("", "file exist===" + localFile.exists());
        if (!localFile.exists()) {
            Log.v("", "inside if===");
            Log.v("", "Parent Filet===" + localFile.getParentFile());
            localFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            // localFile.createNewFile();
            copy(fileSelected, localFile);
        } else {
            Log.v("", "inside else===");
            mCurrentPhotoPath = localFile.getAbsolutePath();
            uploadMediaFile();
        }
```

This copy method copies data from dropbox file to my local storage.

```
private void copy(final Entry fileSelected, final File localFile) {
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(ChatActivity.this,
                "Downloading...", "Please wait...");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                BufferedInputStream br = null;
                BufferedOutputStream bw = null;
                DropboxInputStream fd;
                try {
                    fd = mDBApi.getFileStream(fileSelected.path,
                            localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    br = new BufferedInputStream(fd);
                    bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                            localFile));

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int read;
                    while (true) {
                        read = br.read(buffer);
                        if (read <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    pd.dismiss();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    android.os.Message msg = new android.os.Message();
                    msg.arg1 = 100;
                    if (msg.arg1 >= 100) {
                        progressHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                        mCurrentPhotoPath = localFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    }

                } catch (DropboxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (bw != null) {
                        try {
                            bw.close();
                            if (br != null) {
                                br.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

I am creating file in a folder using localFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
I got above error when I upload this file to server.

how to fix this?

Comment: On which code line do you got this error?

Comment: What is fileSelected? On which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: I am uploading file to server.
At time of uploading i got this exception

Comment: fileSelected is a file name which i got from my dropbox folder

Comment: You make imageFolder.mkdirs()...that needs the permission to write to external storage (because You use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ). Have You set this persmission?

Comment: yes I have set the permission

Comment: You should log `localFile.getAbsolutePath()` to see where you are trying to save. What is the path? Further you said `fileSelected  is a file name which i got from my dropbox folder ` But that can not be true as `fileSelected` is a `File object`. And you strill did not tell which code line provokes your error. Is it with `createNewFile()`?

Comment: Have a look with a file explorer app to see if accidentally your path is a directory. As you could have created it with earlier tries.

Answer (score 3):

If you've tried all other options - and problem still persists - then maybe you have a case when the file you want to create matches name of already existing directory.(which might be earlier created my some call to mkdirs() maybe accidentally).
Example:
You want to save file **Test\test.pdf** but you already have folder **Test\Test.pdf\**